# using Ajax can i call one function in many times in php?

Tags: php, ajax, database, download, using

I want download big data from database
so using ajax call single function who pass limit to download database,

ex-66000 records
can I pass to ajax function values 20000,20000,26000
this way and download database.

thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do this. The PHP function can do whatever you program it to do. If you want to pass multiple parameters, pass them as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think, you can use nested AJAX type structure.

Call the second function when the first function accomplish its AJAX call.

Something Like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "/dosomething",
cache: false,
dataType: "html",
data: { lowerbound:"0"; uperbound: "2000"} ,
success: function(html_input)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/dosomething",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: { lowerbound:"2001"; uperbound: "4000"} ,
        success: function(html_input){
        alert(html_input);
        }
    });                                                                       
}
});
```

I used for 2 iterations.

Another way is that you can pass the variables recursively to the function and perform the desired task. This will help you to scale the functions with n numbers of time.